# Как на C# получить список всех дисковых устройств без использования WMI?

Tags: c#

Как на C# получить список всех дисковых устройств без использования WMI, нужны именно пути к устройству, а не логические разделы, например, \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1

Answer (score 1):

Использовать функции DeviceIoControl, CreateFile из kernel32.dll

Определения брать на pinvoke.net ([DeviceIoControl](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/DeviceIoControl.html))

[Здесь](http://jo0ls-dotnet-stuff.blogspot.ru/2008/12/howto-get-physical-drive-string.html) есть код примера на VB.NET, адаптировать для C# проблем не составит.

Answer (score -2):

[System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives)

Посмотрите вот это. На msdn есть пример.